# Unpermitted parameter error (strong params)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I have a form:

```
= simple_form_for @character do |f|
    = f.input :name
    = f.input :description
    = f.simple_fields_for @movie_characters do |fmc|
        = fmc.association :movie, value_method: :id, label_method: :title
    = f.submit
```

Relationship here is Character has many MovieCharacters and MovieCharacter belongs_to Movie.

params I get from this form look like this:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"6d8n1Z5AC3nF/cqzTInnMr5TyRhZFcGV8ssf5CsNkjskiD9lUL10nVDYeV4i0yS85Q87yNcIi+coFFDf0mpZ4w==", "character"=>{"name"=>"Joker", "description"=>"best villain ever", "movie_character"=>{"movie_id"=>"1"}}, "commit"=>"Update Character", "controller"=>"characters", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"1"}
```

character_params method looks like this:

```
def character_params
        params.require(:character).permit(:name, :description, movie_characters_attributes: [:movie_id, :character_id])
    end
```

Unfortunately while calling this method in controller I get "Unpermitted parameter: movie_character" warning.
I also tried

```
def character_params
            params.require(:character).permit(:name, :description, movie_characters: [:movie_id, :character_id])
        end
```

But effects are the same. Can you tell me why it doesnt work?

UPDATE:

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :movie_characters

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :movie_characters
end

class MovieCharacter < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :character
  belongs_to :movie
end
```

Comment: try `= f.simple_fields_for :movie_characters do |fmc|`

Comment: this doesn't work for you?

Comment: no, its a better solution, but it doesnt work, i updated my question, it now has models code like you asked

Comment: @Leo- model code looks good

Comment: @Sontya I owe you apology, i'm using old computer and dont have autosave feature i'm used to, your first suggestion works, i just didnt have it saved. thank you, sorry for trouble

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. It should be:

```
def character_params
    params.require(:character).permit(:name, :description, movie_character_attributes: [:movie_id, :character_id])
end
```

without "s" in movie_characters_attributes.

Comment: on my side its not a typo, take a look at the example on railsguides: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

Comment: Okay, but see what you send to the controller. There is a  `movie_character` param, so you can try solution suggested by me and check if it works.